# Session variable calls only the last id from mysql table

Tags: php, session

Currently I use `SESSIONS` to call for my varibles from a different page,where multiple data are retrieved from mysql database using a `while()` statement, onto another page. The many retrieved rows has a specific id which is retrieved from the table. Each row also has a link that when clicked takes you to the page 2 to show details of the person marching that id. 
For instance on page1, these are the data shown

```
id | name
1  | Kamena
2  | aman
3  | Forfie
```

sample of my code on page 1

```
session_start();

$stmt="select id,name from table1";
$result=$db->query($stmt);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];

$_SESSION['id']=$id;
echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='page2.php'>id</a></td>
                <td>name</td>
            </tr>
       </table>";
  }
```

On page 2, this is a sample of my codes

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

  $stmt="select id,name from table1 where id=$id";
  $result=$db->query($stmt);
  $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  $perID=$row['perID'];
  $name=$row['name'];
```

The problem here is when the link, id which is 1 with Kamena been the name, is clicked to page 2 the id returns 3 on the page 2 mean while it suppose to return id which is equal to 1. Please is there is something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are writing to SESSION['id'] and overwriting it each time, thus storing the last value only.  You need to do this...

```
$_SESSION['id'][$id] = $id;
```

This way you have access to it, and can access it as a key/value.

So on your next page if the id you want to access is 7, you would access it as such...

```
 echo($_SESSION['id']['7']);
```

But a problem I see, is that you don't know which ID you clicked to be able to access on the next page.  In your link you need to somehow reference it, then check if its in the session.  Which kinda defeats the point of the SESSION variable anyways.  Because then you could just pass it as a GET request

Like so,...

```
  <a href='page2.php?id=7'>PAGE 2</a>
```

And on page two...

```
 if(isset($_GET)){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
 }

 $stmt="select id,name from table1 where id=$id";
 $result=$db->query($stmt);
 $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

This is completely unrecommended though, just highlighting the fact that you need to somehow pass it to the next page, and SESSION isnt the way since you need a way to reference that session somehow anyways.  If you know what Im trying to say.

Comment: I dont want to use get() function at all, I prefer using sessions than to use get.

Comment: No I know....but thats what Im saying, is you somehow have to pass it across the pages.  Storing all the ids in a session is cool, but then on the next page, how would you ever know which id you need to access , without subsequently passing it to that page to check the session....which like I said.  Kinda defeats the whol point of using session in the first place, because you would have to pass it somehow, which in that case you can just pass the id and query the database and avoid session all together...Hopefully you understand what Im trying to say

Comment: not really, but what you mean, is using sessions for this kind of work is not preferable

Comment: Sessions would be good, if you login a user, and then store their user id in it.  That way, as they navigate, they can view their relevant information.  But in this case, you're loading multiple, and the link to the ID has to be passed so that you can access the clicked link.  If you store those all in a session, like I showed.  You still have no way of knowing which link was clicked and which ID to load, unless you pass it in the link via GET or possibly with javascript cookies or something of the sort